# Colors differ between local and shinyapps.io version of R Shiny application

Tags: r, colors, shiny

I am new to R Shiny and am working on my first application.  I've got it looking just how I want it locally, but the colors change when I deploy/publish it to shinyapps.io.  I haven't found anything discussing this on the internet.  I created a simplified version of my application that recreates the color change with deployment.

Locally, the colors look the way I want them to (heat colors):
[image]

On shinyapps.io, the colors look like this:
[image]

I am using RStudio version 0.98.1049 with 64bit R version 3.1.0 on Windows 7.

The three files I'm using are `Server.r`, `ui.r`, and `helper.r`, each shown below.  (*I couldn't figure out how to display the application in showcase mode on shinyapps.io.*)  My "real" application is more complex than this, but I wanted to preserve some of the complexity in case that contributed to the color change issue.  That's why in this example, there are three different functions being used to create a pretty simple plot.

**Server.r**

```
source("helper.r")

mydf <- data.frame(x=rnorm(100), y=rnorm(100), z1=rnorm(100), z2=rnorm(100))

shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  # get metric index number
  mIndex <- reactive({
    match(input$selmetric, metrix)
  })

  # plot the selected metric
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    bigdf <- mydf
    i <- mIndex()
    drawplot(dat=bigdf, metric=input$selmetric)
  })

})
```

**ui.r**

```
shinyUI(fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Color Test"),

  fluidRow(
    column(4,
       # select box
       selectInput(
         "selmetric",
         label = h4("Select metric to plot"),
         choices = list(
           "First" = "z1",
           "Second" = "z2"
         ),
         selected = "z1"
       )
    )
  ),

  fluidRow(
    column(8,
      plotOutput("plot")
    )
  )
))
```

**helper.r**

```
# metric names
metrix <- c("y1", "y2")

# assign a specified number of heat colors to a collection of values
colorn <- function(x, n) {
    group <- cut(x, breaks=n, labels=FALSE)
    colr <- heat.colors(n)[group]
  data.frame(group=group, colr=colr)
  }

# define symbol color and size categories for numeric data
def.sym <- function(x, ngrps=10) {
    gc <- colorn(x, ngrps)
    data.frame(colz=gc$colr, sizes=5*(gc$group/ngrps))
    }

# draw the plot
drawplot <- function(dat, metric) {
    z <- dat[, metric]
    ds <- def.sym(z)
    ord <-  order(-ds$sizes)
    par(mar=c(4, 4, 1, 1), family="mono", xpd=NA, cex=1.5)
    plot(dat$x[ord], dat$y[ord], bg=ds$colz[ord], pch=21, cex=ds$sizes[ord])
    }
```

Comment: Can't you also add a rednerTable() or something to see what values are being set in the color column of `colorn` or `colz` of `def.sym`? Are you sure the values are being set correctly? I'm not sure now if the problem is with the color values you are plotting or with the rendering of those colors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
plot(dat$x[ord], dat$y[ord], bg=as.character(ds$colz[ord]), pch=21, cex=ds$sizes[ord])
```

I added a line `print(str(ds))` right before your plot statement, and here is the output:

```
> runApp()
Listening on http://127.0.0.1:3643
'data.frame':   100 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ colz : Factor w/ 9 levels "#FF0000FF","#FF2400FF",..: 4 6 6 4 3 5 4 8 3 5 ...
 $ sizes: num  2 3 3 2 1.5 2.5 2 4 1.5 2.5 ...
NULL
```

Clearly, the value that you passed to `bg` is actually the color levels 1,2,3..etc. instead of its values "#FFB600FF", "#FFB600F"..., that also explains why most of the color looks "familiar".

Here is how your code looks on my account on [shinyappio](https://bwang.shinyapps.io/heatcolor/)

[image]

In the end, I think it probably has nothing to do with the running environment, instead mostly because of the `factor issue` in your code, you were probably working on some local data frame which happens to have the correct type.

(Note: I have a hard time deploy with the helper.R as a separate file, I copied the content from helper.R to server.R and it worked on shinyappsio in the end.)

Comment: Thanks.  Adding one line of code to the top of the `Server.r` file did the trick: `options(stringsAsFactors=FALSE)`.  I have this option set in my local version of R.